# How to iterate over the loop

Tags: python

I have written this code to iterate through the files 0-100. The problem is when log file 0 is not found it is not going to next file.

I tried to use `return i +1` which did not work as i am new to coding I don't know how to proceed. how to ignore the empty files and proceed to next. Should i keep a counter?

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Bindu\\Documents\\Thesis\\lfiles\\"

list = os.listdir(path)  # dir is your directory path
number_files = len(list)
print(number_files)
try:
      for i in range(0, 100):
        path2 = "data." + str(i) + "\\Log." + str(i)
        file = path + path2

        f = open(file)
        if not os.path.exists(path2):
            with open(path2) as fi:
                if not fi.read(3):  # avoid reading entire file.
                    print("File is empty")

except Exception as e:
     raise SystemExit("File empty")
```

Comment: Why not use `for file in os.listdir(path):`? Then you won't encounter the problem of trying to read a non existent file

Comment: `list` is also a keyword, so I'd advise against using it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SystemExit("File Empty") in the except block,Instead use print("File Empty") .

Answer (score 0):

Your code loops through `0` to `100` while it is not necessary.
Your code should be something like below:

```
import os
import traceback

path = "C:\\Users\\Bindu\\Documents\\Thesis\\lfiles\\"

try:
      for file in os.listdir(path):
        file = path + file

        f = open(file)
        with open(path2) as fi:
            if not fi.read(3):  # avoid reading entire file.
                print("File is empty")

except Exception as e:
     print(traceback.format_exc())
```

And a note on `listdir`:

> os.listdir(path) Return a list containing the names of the entries in
>   the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does
>   not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present
>   in the directory.

So `type(os.listdir('.'))` would give `<type 'list'>` and you can iterate over the result.